# Is there a way to make 2 Textviews of different layouts the same height?

Tags: android, xml, textview

I have two textviews in different layout files. I would like textview 1's height to be dependent on textview 2's height, which is dynamic). Is there a way to do this programmatically or in the xml?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of TextView programmatically as below

```
LayoutParams params = textView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 50;
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [addTextChangedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)) to your `secondTextView` to listen to text changes.

The when the second text change, you update the height of the first one using LayoutParams.

eg:

```
 yourSecondText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

              public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {  

                   LayoutParams secondTextparams = yourSecondText.getLayoutParams();
                   LayoutParams firstTextparams = yourFirsText.getLayoutParams();

                   firstTextparams.height = secondTextparams.height;
                   yourFirsText.setLayoutParams(firstTextparams);
              }

              public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

              public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
           });
```